# How to update flash in Chromium?

Tags: flash, chromium, adobe

I thought Linux wasn't getting any new updates from Adobe? but i started to get this message a few days ago on youtube and other flash sites:

[image]

When trying to install the update I get to a page which only offers YUM, .tar.gz, and .rpm and none .deb

[image]

Could someone guide me trough installing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install it via the repositories:

```
apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: That's what I'm getting:`
Package flashplugin-nonfree is a virtual package provided by:
  adobe-flashplugin 1:20171010.1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  flashplugin-installer 27.0.0.159ubuntu0.16.04.1
You should explicitly select one to install.`

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use adobe flashplayer anymore from April 2014. [1]

You should rely on pepper flash plugin, install it with [2]:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:skunk/pepper-flash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pepflashplugin-installer

gksu gksu gedit /etc/chromium-browser/default
```

- paste '. /usr/lib/pepflashplugin-installer/pepflashplayer.sh' on the end of the new opened file

References:

[1] http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/01/chromium-npapi-flash-dropped-april-2014

[2] http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-pepper-flash-player-for.html

Answer (score 1):

These instructions will install Pepper flash player for Chromium and it will also be updated automatically. Because Google ended support for Chrome on 32-bit Linux in March, 2016, Pepper flash player can only be installed for 64-bit versions of Chromium.

To install flash player in Chromium web browser search the Dash for Software & Updates and open the Software & Updates window. Click the *Other Software* tab in the Software & Updates window and put a check mark in the checkbox to the left of where it says: **Canonical Partners**.

[image]

Click the *Close* button to close the Software & Updates window.

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree # remove pepperflashplugin-nonfree if it's installed
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

---

#### Original answer

You can install Chromium web browser together with the Pepper Flash Player in Ubuntu 14.04 and onward (but not in Ubuntu 12.04) from the Ubuntu Software Center. Open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for Pepper Flash Player.

If a more recent version of Pepper Flash Player has been released and you want to update Pepper Flash Player to the latest version, you can do this from the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree --install
```

Pepper Flash Player cannot be updated with the following command anymore on 32-bit OSs since Google ended support for Chrome on 32-bit Linux in March, 2016. If you <s>are using Ubuntu 32-bit</s> were using Ubuntu 32-bit before March, 2016, you can update Pepper Flash Player to the latest version from the terminal using the following command:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree:i386 --install
```

Either of these two commands will download the latest version of Google Chrome (the file is larger than 40MB) and then update only the Pepper Flash Player with the more recent version of Pepper Flash Player that comes with Google Chrome without installing Google Chrome.

If updating Pepper Flash Player to the latest version fails with an error like this:

```
ERROR: failed to retrieve status information from google : W: There is no public key available for the following key IDs:  
1397BC53640DB551
```

It happens because Google changed its signing key. To fix it run the following commands:

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
gpg --export --armor 1397BC53640DB551 | sudo sh -c 'cat >> /usr/lib/pepperflashplugin-nonfree/pubkey-google.txt'
```

...and then try to update Pepper Flash Player to the latest version again.